# Need jquery slider in thumbnail area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-slider

I am working on a project http://www.node.au.com. in the home page as you can see a lot of images and what I need to do is put a slider for those images that have more than one image so that user can see it without clicking the image that this particular image have more than one image like in http://themes.swiftpsd.com/clique/ and also I need the same caption for title of the image when mouse hover on image as in the above reference link. I searched for it but could not find it.

here is my code

```
    <ul id="fdgSlides">
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'two2_project_featured_image',true)==1){
    $showFeat = false; } else { $showFeat = true; } $nvideoshtml5 = 1; $naudios = 1; 

$images = two2_get_project_media('thumbnail','large_slideshow',$showFeat);     
    if(count($images)>0){ foreach($images as $image){ ?>
```

Comment: 29 people visit my question but no one answer it. if my question is wrong or incomplete then kindly let me know so that i could edit it.

Comment: I think the  term "slider" is a bit not clear . what do you mean by "slider" ? inside the original div ? outside ? overlay ?

Comment: Your question is just too broad. You're not really asking anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think nivoslider can help you alot.
[Nivoslider site](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/)

Here are a wordpress plugin integrated it with wordpress [HERE](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nivo-slider/)

And this a tutorial to fully integrate it with wordpress [HERE](http://www.blogohblog.com/how-to-integrate-nivo-slider-into-wordpress/).

Hope it help you :)